# How to POST infinite number of parameters in c# function through API

Tags: c#, parameters

So I have thisfunction I have to make. All previous functions have been made pretty much the same way like so:

```
[Route("MemberInfo"), HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult ArrayTest([FromBody]Member member)
{
    using (var db = new DBContext())
    {
        var member = db.Members.Where(m => m.email == loginForm.email).FirstOrDefault();
        if (member != null)
        {
            return Ok(new { success = true, message = member });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "Invalid email or password" });
        }
    }
}
```

Just an example, there are a lot more lines of code in that function but it was just an example of how I write them.

I use Google's Advanced REST client to make sure all my functions are working. For MemberInfo I give this with the POST option clicked and content-type is application/json:

```
{
  email: "blahblah@gmail.com",
  password: "123456789"
}
```

and I get all my info.

These function are used by another developer who is creating my iPhone app. I am in the process of creating a function to refer a friend/friends.

I created a little test to see how infinite parameters work(in case there are multiple referred emails):

```
[Route("ArrayTest"), HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult ArrayTest(params string[] emails)
{            
    string emailSentence = "";
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < emails.Length; i++ )
    {
        emailSentence += emails[i] + ", ";
    }

    return Ok(new { success = true, emails = emailSentence });
}
```

I am having trouble inputing the parameters, how can I do that?

I try it like this:

```
{
  ("hello", "buhbye", "ella")
}
```

and it says "{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}"

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid JSON. You can validate your request by running it through [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

Try this instead, post the emails as an array

```
{
    "emails": [
        "hello",
        "buhbye",
        "ella"
    ]
}
```

Comment: @user3861672, can you post how you're posting the emails and the request that is sent to the server? It should work as long as you set the contentType.